# Do all 404 pages share something in common?/Are 404 page distinguishable from regular pages?

Tags: django

Say I am running stumbleupon.com and users can submit sites to be added into the db of sites. Is there a way that I can write a program to see whether or not the site that was added by the user is actually a real website? Or if it bring me to a 404 that I can say "welp, that was some bugus" or maybe that the user made an error when submitting the url? Or do i need to put people on my payroll to see if the user submitted website bring me to a 404?

Answer (score 4):

The response code from the request is a 404 not found, instead of a 200 success message that you get on a good response from the server.  You can easily automate the check.

Comment: Note that in some rare circumstances clueless web admins have been known to configure their web servers to return a 'not found' page with a 200 status code.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know much about python, I offer a client side solution.

You could check if the URL is legit as soon as the user submits the page.  Maybe throw up a 'verifying url' message or something.

Using [this method](http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/error-handling.html) you could make a cross domain call to see if that site is really there.  Then you could pop up a message that asks them to fix their mistake or allow the URL to be submitted.  This solution uses Yahoo as a proxy, but as you can see by my super simple function below it does work.

```
function doAjaxCheck(url){
// if the URL starts with http
if(url.match('^http')){

  //add a 'loading message here, or something'        

  // assemble the YQL call      
  $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        alert('it is OK');
      } else {
        alert('not OK');
      }
    }
  );
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    timeout:5000,
    success: function(data){
      alert('it is OK');
    },
    error: function(req,error){          
      if(error === 'error'){error = req.statusText;}
        alert('not OK : ' + error );
    }
  });
}
}
```

However, all this being said, I would go with a server-side check for reliability-sake.